# Change position/location of Axis Labels

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

I would like to change the position of the X-axis so that the labels appear at the top rather than the bottom (see image):

[image]

I have achieved this in the past but now I can't remember!

I have tried changing the label specs, for "position" but with no luck!

Any help is greatly appreciated

Edit:
Perhaps the only alternative is the example below?
[image]

Edit 2.0:
I experimented with "Position": - and managed to get the Axis labels in the correct place, but I think this is an accident and incorrect syntax. I'm unable to change the offset here as well

[image]

Comment: Can you share your spec with data or a sample .pbix?

Comment: Thanks Davide, I've added you to my Github Repo - the link is here: https://github.com/PBIQueryous/PBIXs/blob/main/OnyxDataChallenge_Oct23.pbix

You *should* have access! Let me know if there's any problems. :) - I'm immensely grateful for your help.

It's the first page in the PBIX file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're after? If so, just add an orient and adjust the spacing.

[image]

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "spacing": 5,
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "spacing": 5,
      "hconcat": [
        {
          
          "name": "MainMatrix",
          "mark": {
            "type": "rect",
            "tooltip": {
              "content": "data"
            }
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "DayNameShort",
              "type": "nominal",
              "sort": null,
              "axis": {"title": null, "orient":"top"}
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "MonthShort",
              "axis": {"title": null},
              "sort": null
            },
            "fill": {
              "field": "Streams",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "legend": null
            },
            "opacity": {
              "condition": {
                "test": {
                  "field": "_selected_",
                  "equal": "off"
                },
                "value": 0.3
              },
              "value": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "RowBar",
          "width": 70,
          "mark": {
            "type": "bar",
            "height": {"band": 0.95},
            "tooltip": true,
            "color": "#1DB954"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "y": {
              "field": "MonthShort",
              "axis": null,
              "sort": null
            },
            "x": {
              "field": "Streams",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "axis": {
                "labels": false,
                "title": null
              }
            },
            "opacity": {
              "condition": {
                "test": {
                  "field": "_selected_",
                  "equal": "off"
                },
                "value": 0.3
              },
              "value": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "hconcat": [
        {
          "name": "ColBar",
          "height": 50,
          "mark": {
            "type": "bar",
            "width": {"band": 0.95},
            "tooltip": true,
            "color": "#1DB954"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "DayNameShort",
              "sort": null,
              "axis": null
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Streams",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "scale": {
                "reverse": true
              },
              "axis": {
                "labels": false,
                "title": null
              }
            }
          },
          "opacity": {
            "condition": {
              "test": {
                "field": "_selected_",
                "equal": "off"
              },
              "value": 0.3
            },
            "value": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Davide, this is exactly what i was looking for! Please accept my apologies for bothering you with such a trivial endeavour, I got lost in the sea of documentation and couldn' this solution. I'm indebted to you. Marked as Solution and upvoted!

Comment: Not a problem and any time ;)